# How to access a specific index in a array of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct A

{
    int a;
};

int main()

{
    A* ptr = new A[3];
    ptr->a = 3;
    return ptr->a;
}
```

The code above returns '3' as expected, and it evaluates to the first index. But how can I access the second index using the member selection operator? I could get it to work this way:`(*(ptr+1)).a=5`
But the code wouldn't be clear.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptr` is a pointer to an array of `A` objects.  You can apply the `[]` index operator directly to the pointer to access specific objects in the array, eg:

```cpp
A* ptr = new A[3];
...
ptr[index].a = 3;
...
delete[] ptr;
```

`pointer[index]` (and even `index[pointer]`) is exactly the same as doing `*(pointer+index)`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I wonder how I didn't try this way before. I guess my question looks silly now xD